# Standard application of Oort-Tate classification theorem

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, group-schemes, abelian-schemes, modular-curves

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tors}{tors}$In Mazur's paper “[Modular curves and the Eisenstein ideals](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Mazur77.pdf)”, on the bottom of page 159, it says that if $T$ is a open subscheme of $\Spec\mathbb{Z}$ over which $2$ is invertible in $O(T)$, $A$ is an abelian $T$-group scheme, and $p$ is any prime giving a closed point of $T$, then the specialization map $A(T)_{\tors}\rightarrow A(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is injective.

Mazur says that this is a standard application of the Oort-Tate classification theorem, which classifies all commutative group scheme of prime order over a base scheme.

So the question is how to prove the specializationn map is injective with the use of the classifiation theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose $A$ is flat and proper over $T$. Then if the map is not injective, there is an element of prime order in the kernel. Such an element gives rise to a finite flat subgroup scheme of $T$ of prime order $l$ with generic fibre isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z}$. Presumably the classification then shows that such a group scheme must be constant.

Comment: @ulrich Thanks for your answer. I want to know why we need $2$ is invertible in $O(T)$, and why can't $A$ have a constant subgroup scheme?

Comment: There is an obvious counterexample if $2$ is not invertible.

Comment: @ulrich do you mean the group scheme of square roots of $1$?

Comment: @vrz: Yes, this is clearly the simplest counterexample.